# AngularJS how to style JSON message

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to style the JSON message to the required style.

the required style of JSON message looks like:

```
[   
{
“question”: “Write down Nhat’s email”,
    “answer”: “nhat@taie.com.au”,
    “inline”: true
},
{
<% NEXT QUESTION/ANSWER %>
},
{
<%…%>
}
]
```

and currently my JSON message looks like:

[{"Question":"Question","Note":"","notePlaceholder":"enter text","inlineChecked":false},{"Question":"Question","Note":"","notePlaceholder":"enter text...","inlineChecked":""}]

Any idea on that?

[This is the link of my code](http://plnkr.co/edit/7erVt8?p=preview)

Comment: Are you trying to add line breaks into a JSON display in a UI?

Comment: @Reboog711 yes,correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`json`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json) filter on the object in a `pre` tag.

```
 <pre>{{json | json}}</pre>
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NSvvYD?p=preview)

Regarding your question, you could add a `$watchCollection` on `json`, and in the handler iterate through the items and delete the property you don't want.

```
   $scope.$watchCollection('json', function(values) {
      angular.forEach(values, function(item) {
        delete item.notePlaceholder;
      });
    });
```

Note, you're simply passing a reference from `$scope.items` to `$scope.json`, so if you modify one it will modify the other. If you don't want that, use `angular.copy` to make a separate copy. I've also update the plunk.

Comment: btw, how should i remove one item, like "notePlacehoder" in the json message?

Comment: you could add a watch on that item, so when it changes you could call `delete $scope.json.notePlaceholder;` or something like that